# Unable to send mail from GitLab

Tags: exchange-server, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I'm trying to configure GitLab to send mail with Microsoft Exchange, however it doesn't work, no email is sent from gitlab to user

Here is my configuration:

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "mail.company.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 25
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "gitlab@company.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "PASSWORD"
```

I also implemented a snip of code with Java mail, and it sent mail successfully, here is the Java Mail configuration:

```
final String username = "gitlab@company.com";
final String password = "PASSWORD";
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.company.com");
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
```

Can anyone point out how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A full exchange configuration should also contain the following lines:

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "smtp.company.com" # SMTP domain to use
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login" # Use login credentials
```

[Source](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/smtp.md)

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to configure GitLab to send mail with Microsoft Exchange

That shouldn't be possible/easy *before* [GitLab 11.7 (January 22nd, 2019)](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/01/22/gitlab-11-7-released/) 3+ years later after the OP.

See "[GitLab now supports Microsoft Exchange and Google Groups for incoming email features like Service Desk](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/01/23/support-microsoft-exchange-google-groups-incoming-email/)"

> As of GitLab 11.7, you can now use either Microsoft Exchange or Google Groups with your self-managed GitLab instance, configured as an email server, giving you even more options when setting up incoming email functionality.
>
> Previously, these features were available to self-managed GitLab users only if your email server supported **[sub-addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Common_local-part_semantics)**. ([illustrated here](https://serverfault.com/a/201304/783))
>   Microsoft Exchange and Google Groups do not support sub-addressing.
>
> GitLab 11.7 now supports both sub-addressing and catch-all email mailboxes, enabling compatibility with these two popular options that do provide catch-all email mailboxes.

See that [configuration example](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/incoming_email.html#omnibus-package-installations) (for an Omnibus installation)

```
 gitlab_rails['incoming_email_enabled'] = true

 # The email address including the `%{key}` placeholder that will be replaced to reference the item being replied to.
 # The placeholder can be omitted but if present, it must appear in the "user" part of the address (before the `@`).
 # Exchange does not support sub-addressing, so a catch-all mailbox must be used.
 gitlab_rails['incoming_email_address'] = "incoming-%{key}@exchange.example.com"

 # Email account username
 # Typically this is the userPrincipalName (UPN)
 gitlab_rails['incoming_email_email'] = "incoming@ad-domain.example.com"
 # Email account password
 gitlab_rails['incoming_email_password'] = "[REDACTED]"

 # IMAP server host
 gitlab_rails['incoming_email_host'] = "exchange.example.com"
 # IMAP server port
 gitlab_rails['incoming_email_port'] = 993
 # Whether the IMAP server uses SSL
 gitlab_rails['incoming_email_ssl'] = true
```

And yes, that is available for *all* versions of GitLab, including the Core "CE" one ("Community Edition", which is free).
See [release notes](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/01/22/gitlab-11-7-released/#support-catch-all-email-mailboxes-including-microsoft-exchange-and-google-groups-for-incoming-email-features):

> GitLab has some great features that use incoming email, such as reply by email, new issue by email, new merge request by email, and service desk. Previously, you could only take advantage of these features if you used an email server configured to use sub-addressing.
>
> With this release, GitLab now supports both sub-addressing and catch-all email mailboxes, using a new email format, allowing more email servers to be used with GitLab, including Microsoft Exchange and Google Groups (which do not support sub-addressing).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and managed to fix it with this config:

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.company.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 587
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "gitlab@company.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = 'PASS'
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "smtp.company.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
#gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'gitlab@conpany.com'
```